# How to send mail with binary word in mail subject using PHP

Tags: php, email, unicode, encoding, internationalization

I am going to send mail through a PHP website. The client may customize the mail subject and I will get the post data in UTF-8. But when I send out an HTML e-mail using the PHP mail(),
I found that the subject does not show properly but the body does.

How do I send a chinese word in the PHP mail function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode the subject according to how *encoded-word* is specified (see RFC 2047):

```
encoded-word = "=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="
```

You can either use

- the Base64 encoding ([`base64_encode`](http://docs.php.net/base64_encode)):

  ```
  'Subject: =?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?='
  ```

  or
- the *quoted-printable* encoding (see RFC 2045, [`imap_8bit`](http://docs.php.net/imap_8bit)):

  ```
  'Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?'.imap_8bit($subject).'?='
  ```

Comment: For some newbies like me, set the $subject value using:
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
if you are using UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

It's quite involved to send non-ASCII in mail header. Check out PHPMailer,

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/

If it doesn't work for you, look at encoderHeader() to see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I use [PEAR Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime) and [mb_encode_mimeheader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-mimeheader.php) to encode the subject. Here it is a working function example:

```
<?php
function mail_html($from, $to, $subject, $message_html, $headers = array()) {
  require_once "Mail.php";
  require_once 'Mail/mime.php';
  $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array (
        'host' => 'smtp.example.com',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'user@example.com',
        'password' => 'password'));

  if(function_exists('mb_internal_encoding'))
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
  if(function_exists('mb_encode_mimeheader'))
    $subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject,"UTF-8", "B", "\n");

  $h = array();
  $h['From']         = "$from";
  $h['Bounce']       = "$from";
  $h['Reply-To']     = "$from";
  $h['Return-Path']  = "$from";
  $headers['Subject']      = $subject;
  $headers = array_merge($h, $headers);

  $mime = new Mail_mime();  
  $mime->setHTMLBody($message_html);
  $body = $mime->get(array('html_charset' => 'UTF-8', 'html_encoding' => '8bit', 'head_charset'=> 'UTF-8'));
  $hdrs = $mime->headers($headers);  
  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $hdrs, $body);

  if (PEAR::isError($mail))
    echo 'error', 'Unable to send email';
  else
    echo "Sent email to $to from $from";
}
?>
```